# Is there a better way to insert a sheet from a excel workbook into a list?

Tags: list, vsto, excel

I have this bit of code that I use to read a sheet from a excel workbook and then populate a list.

I'm getting a range, putting it into a two-dimensional array and then going through it with a for cycle and populating the list.

My question is, is there a better way to achieve the same result? I mean, with less code and faster.
I have to do this for 4 sheets and it takes 260ms.

```cs
public static void LoadDdrDataIntoObjects(ref List<Receivables> recList, ref List<Dilution> dilList, ref List<Accountable> accList, ref List<Outstanding> outList, string sheet)
{
    Workbook pantaReiWorkBook = PantaReiApplication.ActiveWorkbook;
    Sheets pantaReiWorkSheets = pantaReiWorkBook.Sheets;

    Worksheet pantaReiWorkSheet = pantaReiWorkSheets[sheet];
    Range pantaReiLastCell =
        pantaReiWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);

    Range pantaReiRange =
        pantaReiWorkSheet.Range["A1:" + pantaReiLastCell.Address.Trim(new char['$']), Type.Missing];

    object[,] pantaReidataRange = (object[,]) pantaReiRange.Value[Type.Missing];

    for (var row = 2; row <= pantaReidataRange.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        Receivables pantaReiReceivable = new Receivables
        {
            FileID = fileID.ID,
            SheetType =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 1].ToString(),
            SellerCompany =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 2].ToString(),
            Contract = pantaReidataRange[row, 3].ToString(),
            DebitID = pantaReidataRange[row, 4].ToString(),
            CompanyCode =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 5].ToString(),
            NoteNumber =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 6].ToString(),
            Installment =
                Convert.ToInt32(pantaReidataRange[row, 7]),
            InvoiceDate =
                (DateTime) pantaReidataRange[row, 8],
            DueDate1 = (DateTime) pantaReidataRange[row, 9],
            DueDate2 =
                (DateTime) pantaReidataRange[row, 10],
            DueDate3 =
                (DateTime) pantaReidataRange[row, 11],
            Currency =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 12].ToString(),
            Amount =
                (float)
                Convert.ToDouble(pantaReidataRange[row, 13]),
            Sign = pantaReidataRange[row, 14].ToString(),
            ProductType =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 15].ToString(),
            DilutionType =
                Convert.ToString(pantaReidataRange[row, 16]),
            MaturityStatus =
                Convert.ToInt32(pantaReidataRange[row, 17]),
            DebitStatus =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 18].ToString(),
            DealerFlag =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 19].ToString(),
            CustomerDescription =
                pantaReidataRange[row, 20].ToString(),
            AssetType =
                Convert.ToInt32(pantaReidataRange[row, 21])
        };

        recList.Add(pantaReiReceivable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed on my own. I used reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to profile your code. [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is a tool that I use often.

One suggestion that I have is, if you have quite a large number of rows to process, consider either setting the `List<T>` capacity up front, or even deferring the addition of the individual record objects to the `List` until you're done processing - put them into an array during the looping. You can declare the array before you enter the for-loop; you already know the size of the array, based on the iteration count of the for-loop. Once you're done processing, you can collect all the arrays and LINQ transform them into the lists as you please.